# How do I run a program in Ubuntu using Wine that requires JRE?

Tags: ubuntu, wine, jre

I have an application that requires JRE to run on Windows. I have now migrated to Ubuntu and am trying to run the same application using WINE. However I get the error: "No Java Found".

Any ideas how I can run the application?

Comment: Is it a windows application that needs JRE or is it a Java application?

Answer (score 4):

If it is a Java app it will just work on Java in Linux - without WINE.

Comment: Thanks sybreon!!! It was an exe but somehome I managed to extract the contents and run it on Linux!!!

Comment: If it is compiled as desktop application using eclipse swt it will not run on any platform without wine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the windows JRE in WINE? This page says it works: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1372